# Compound literals in C: do they create duplicate copies?

Tags: c, optimization, struct, c99, compound-literals

I have always wondered about compound literals in C, do they create duplicate copies?

Take the following two examples for instance. The only difference between the two are few lines of code, respectively

```c
book->book_id = book_id;
book->price = price;
book->isbn = isbn;
```

in the first example, and

```c
*book = (Book) {
    .book_id = book_id,
    .price = price,
    .isbn = isbn
};
```

in the second example.

My question is simple: Does the second example allocate a `Book` structure *in the stack first* and then copy it into the heap, or does the second example behave exactly like the first example, and simply populates the structure already allocated in the heap without touching the stack?

**Example 1**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Book_T {
    unsigned int book_id;
    unsigned int price;
    long unsigned int isbn;
} Book;


Book * new_book (
    const unsigned int book_id,
    const unsigned int price,
    const long unsigned int isbn
) {

    Book * book = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    if (!book) {

        return NULL;

    }

    book->book_id = book_id;
    book->price = price;
    book->isbn = isbn;

    return book;

}


int main (
    const int argc,
    const char * argv[]
) {

    Book * my_book = new_book(12944, 39, 9783161484100);

    if (!my_book) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;

    }

    /*  Do something with `my_book`...  */

    free(my_book);

    return 0;

}
```

**Example 2**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Book_T {
    unsigned int book_id;
    unsigned int price;
    long unsigned int isbn;
} Book;


Book * new_book (
    const unsigned int book_id,
    const unsigned int price,
    const long unsigned int isbn
) {

    Book * book = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    if (!book) {

        return NULL;

    }

    *book = (Book) {
        .book_id = book_id,
        .price = price,
        .isbn = isbn
    };

    return book;

}


int main (
    const int argc,
    const char * argv[]
) {

    Book * my_book = new_book(12944, 39, 9783161484100);

    if (!my_book) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;

    }

    /*  Do something with `my_book`...  */

    free(my_book);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you declared them as `static`, there would be more chance that the compiler could do aggressive optimizations.

Comment: @Neil But statistically speaking most of the structures that people populate are located in the heap. My question is more like “Given that I have to populate any `struct`, is example #2 as performant/optimized as example #1?”

Comment: The assembly looks the same to me.  GCC https://godbolt.org/z/7jd77d4o9  CLANG https://godbolt.org/z/jWbMo8Gs3  You could try different compilers and optimization flags but I suspect it will be the same or nearly the same.

Comment: A non-optimizing compiler might populate the stack and then copy.  But I would expect that any decent optimizing compiler would optimize out the copy.  It seems like a very basic optimization to notice that  "move immediate to stack ; move stack to heap ; never use stack again" can be optimized into "move immediate to heap".

Comment: Thank you all for your insight. Would you suggest that using example #2 is a coding practice as good as using example #1? Based on your personal taste, which one of the two examples would you normally use?

Comment: @madmurphy (it was an unrelated observation :].) #1 is a valid C90 programme, #2 requires C99. In this case, the syntactic sugar buys you no advantage, so I would lean toward #1, (but I'm highly biased.)

Comment: @Neil: Another distinction which isn't relevant here, but would be relevant in some other scenarios, is that when using discrete assignments, one need only write the portions of the structure whose values will actually matter.  If e.g. one has `struct countedThing { uint16_t count; uint16_ dat[15]; };` and writes `myThing->count = 2; myThing->dat[0] =1; myThing->dat[1] = 2;`, a compiler need not generate code that writes anything to `myThing->dat[2..15]`.  If one had used a compound literal, a compiler would have been required to generate code to zero out all of the remaining elements.

Comment: @supercat The opposite of your observation holds too though. Imagine that the `struct` in the two examples had 100 fields and our function needed to populate all of them. In the first example the compiler would need to read the address of `book` and add a different number to that address a hundred times, while in the second example the compiler would use hard-coded addresses a hundred times to populate the compound literal and then copy the entire literal using `memcpy()`, which is very efficient. The difference will probably be ridicolously small, but it would be a case where the sugar wins.

Comment: @madmurphy: A decent compiler should typically be able to consolidate the address calculations when consecutive instructions access fields of the same structure.  In cases where copying a static const structure would be better, using a named static const object will achieve that without C99 syntactic sugar.  Using a compound literal may or may not have that same effect.

Answer (score 2):

In the abstract machine (which is how C is defined) the compound literal at block scope creates an object in automatic storage. The object will be destroyed at the end of the function.

"stack" and "heap" are implementation details (which some implementations don't have). The only requirements on the implementation are to produce the same observable behaviour as the abstract machine,  it does not have to replicate the abstract machine's memory usage.  So the real machine could generate the same executable for both of your examples.

Comment: Thank you, M.M. So, _in the abstract machine_ an object is created in the automatic storage and then copied to the location pointed by `book` (wherever this points to). That means: two copies. But how about _the concrete machine_? How do compilers implement my two examples? Are they smart enough to understand that in the second example a copy of the object in the automatic storage is not needed and the two examples are equivalent?

Comment: @madmurphy Some are smart enough, some may not be . You could try it out in your machine and inspect the assembly

Answer (score 1):

If a compiler can see everything that will be done with a constant literal object, it may be able to omit code that would reserve and release space for it.  For example, given:

```
struct S foo;
...
foo = (struct S foo){1,2,3};
```

a compiler could generate code that would simply store 1, 2, and 3 directly into the first items of `foo` and zero to the rest (if any), rather than generating a new temporary object and copying it.

Unfortunately, there is no way to invite a compiler to refrain from constructing a temporary object in cases where code takes the address of a compound literal and uses it in ways the compiler can't see.  Given e.g.

```
extern void someFunction(struct foo const *p);
...
someOutSideFunction(&(struct foo){1,2,3});
```

a compiler would not be allowed to substitute:

```
extern void someFunction(struct foo const *p);
...
static struct foo const __const24601 = {1,2,3};
someOutSideFunction(&__const24601);
```

unless it knew that someFunction would not both cause the aforementioned function call to get invoked recursively and compare the addresses of the pointers passed to the nested invocations.  As of C18, the only way to allow the compiler to generate code that is as efficient as the latter form would be for a programmer to define a named constant object and pass its address as shown in that example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I perfectly understand that using _the address_ of a compound literal requires the literal to exist, and therefore be allocated somewhere (which means in the stack). But it is not a coincidence that I chose an example without address. In my example the compiler must know that the only purpose of the anonymous compound literal will be that of being copied by value, and such literal will have no meaningful life afterwards; why creating it at all then?

Comment: @madmurphy: I really wish C99 had specified that a compound literal would be an lvalue if and only if all members were compile-time constants, and then specified semantics similar to strings: having addresses, but not necessarily unique ones.

Comment: Theoretically making a const qualified compound literal should be enough. `(const struct foo) { ... }`. Take a look on https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p7. Is says "compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate distinct objects.". So the compiler should be allowed to make over-mentioned optimizations.

Comment: @tstanisl: The Standard allows compilers to place const-qualified static literals in static storage, but does not have any way of specifying a compound literal with static duration, which could be freely read by outside code even after the function containing it has returned.

Comment: The mentioned part of the standard does not say anything about "static" storage. It basically says that strictly-compliant program should not rely on assumption that const-qualified compound literals have different addresses. IMO, the compilers are allowed to treat those literals as if they had static storage. The fact that compilers do not take advantage from this rule looks like missed opportunity for optimization.

Comment: @tstanisl: My point is that there's no way that programmers who *require* that an object have static duration can create it without having to assign it an identifier name.